# I can't download scipy for python on raspberry pi

Tags: python, scipy, pip, raspberry-pi

I try to download scipy for python on raspberry pi(CM3+).

```sh
$ python -m pip install scipy --user
```

But, I can't and the following error appears

what should I do?

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-mEb21z/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n','\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install 
--record /tmp/pip-record-5cX2pH/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user 
--prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-mEb21z/scipy/

Failed cleaning build dir for scipy

Failed building wheel for scipy
```

Comment: Have you tried the python3 version `sudo apt-get install python3-scipy`

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Dwight Foster. My problem is solved.